# Junction table without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, junction-table

Say I have a junction table to resolve a many to many relationship I have between two tables. My junction table also has its own 'Method' column to describe the relationship.
[image: Junction Table Example]

Normally, I would make a composite primary key of [a], [b] and [method] (the method needs to be part of what makes a row unique), but my problem is that [method] field can be NULL. Therefore I cannot add it to the primary key.

So what I've done is create a unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE A_B ADD UNIQUE INDEX `Unique` (`a`, `b`, `method`);
```

The table has no primary key. Is this an okay thing to do or do I need to do something differently?

Comment: A primary key in your junction table may not be necessary, but things I would consider include: (1) a unique index or primary key prevents duplication (redundancy) of data; (2) a primary key is helpful when updating/deleting rows because it removes ambiguity about the row being targeted. FWIW even though you can include a nullable column in a unique index, MySQL does not enforce key uniqueness when part of the key is NULL i.e. you can only have one 'a','b','x' row, but any number of 'a','b',NULL rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a primary key is not the only way to ensure records uniqueness.  There is a unique constraint you can implement to accomplish what is needed.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: I am forcing uniqueness through the unique index I added, so I should be good there. From a DB design perspective, it is okay to not have a key on a junction table?

Comment: Although uniqueness can be enforced through a constraint without an index, using a unique index is usually the better choice (assuming more than a "few" rows). I would only omit indexes on foreign key columns where the table is guaranteed to only ever have just a handful of rows.